# How to save screenshots with unique files names using Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is is possible for Selenium Webdriver to create screenshots with unique file names? If I use the standard command `browser.save_screenshot(screenshot.png)`, my Python script overrides the saved screenshot every time it takes a screenshot.

If, however, I do something like the following to create a unique file name and try to parse the string as a function argument, it doesn't work because apparently Python doesn't do that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
date_stamp = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0]
date_stamp = date_stamp.replace(" ","_")
file_name = date_stamp + ".png"
browser.save_screenshot(file_name)
```

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly?  Do you mean that `save_screenshot` complains about the resulting name?  What you've got generates filenames with `:` characters in them, is that problematic for your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date_stamp` returns something like `"2017-06-09_20:56:54.png"` which is not acceptable file name. Try to use

```
date_stamp = date_stamp.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_").replace("-", "_")
```

which should return you valid name

```
"2017_06_09_20_56_54.png"
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

@classmethod
def tearDown(cls):
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    cls.driver.get_screenshot_as_file('reports/screenshot-%s.png' % now)
```

I have like this. When test finishes, it generate screenshot with creation time in name